# OpenBSD not responding to arp queries

Tags: networking, linux-networking, openbsd

I am setting up an OpenBSD system as a router, I have one interface as the upstream, then another with a vlan configured:

Upstream(em0):

```
inet 10.0.2.20 255.255.255.0 NONE description upstream
```

Downstream(em1):

```
up
```

VLAN10:

```
inet 172.18.10.1 255.255.255.0 NONE vlan 10 vlandev em1
```

When I ping 172.18.10.1 from a client with a static IP of 172.18.10.10, and run a tcpdump on my OpenBSD box I get the ARP queries:

```
Jun 20 16:40:16.170853 08:00:27:9c:0c:38 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 0806 60: arp who-has 172.18.10.1 tell 172.18.10.10
```

So it is clearly receiving the arps, but is not responding.

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit:
[Here is the routing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK8Hi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any managable switch between OpenBSD and the client? You have to configure VLAN 10 at client side also.

Untagged packet will left client but Openbsd is waiting for packets tagged by VLAN10. So somebody have to tag packets with VLAN10.

Solutions are:

1. on managable sw:

   - interface connected to client: access port, VLAN10
   - interface connected to OpenBSD: trunk port
2. have no managable switch:

   - on the client you have to configure VALN10 as well